# Why is index method not called when action name is not specified

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple ASP.NET Core API with the following controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok("index");
    }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("get");
    }
}
```

When I hit URL:

```
"http://localhost:6001/api/home"
```

With a `GET` request, I get the following error:

```
"The request matched multiple endpoints."
```

Normally, if I don't specify an action name, shouldn't it call the `Index()` method?

Comment: If you change the action `Get` to another name would you get the same error?

Comment: There seems to be no effect on what the name of the action is. Neither "Index" nor "Get" has a special effect in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core API, action methods are matched by a combination of HTTP verb used as attribute on the method (which is `HttpGet` by default if you don't add any) and the route parameter used with it. In that sense both your action methods looks similar to the routing system. It sees two `HttpGet` method with no route parameter. That's why both method matches the request -

```cs
"http://localhost:6001/api/home"
```

making the routing system confused which to select. That's exactly what the error message is saying.

You need to make your non-default action method more specific, so that the routing mechanism can differentiate between the two. Something like -

```cs
[HttpGet("data")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok("get");
}
```

Now your `Index` method will be matched as default action method with the above URL.

Comment: So, for Index to act as default, should I be in an MVC environment? Could you explain the difference?

Comment: @M.Azyoksul I really don't have any idea about routing in Razor Pages applications (if that's what you have in mind as a non-MVC environment). For MVC, there are two routing strategies available in Asp.Net Core. What I mentioned in the answer is specific to `Attribute Routing` which is used by Asp.Net Core API by default. For further detail take a look at - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ar

Answer (score 2):

Both of your endpoints are identical. Use routes to differentiate them. For example:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok("index");
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("data")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("get");
    }
}
```

This would open up:

```
http://localhost:6001/api/home/
```

and

```
http://localhost:6001/api/home/data
```

respectively using GET

You could also change the verb, for example use `HttpGet` for one and `HttpPost` for another.

Comment: The question isn't how to explicitly define routes, it's how to _implicitly_ route to the index method when no method has been specified (i.e. without mentioning "index" in the url.

Comment: You can't. You have to differentiate them some how. I changed the index to be default GET, but you can't have 2 default GETs, which is what he was doing.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm saying you didn't _address it_ in your answer.